# Ajax Timeout in different Network

Tags: php, ajax, excel, extjs, timeout

I have searched all over the net about this problem and a bunch came out but they did not provide a definite solution for the problem.

The issue is that, I have Web Application, this is already in a public DNS, that generates report and then exports this as Excel file. When I try this in my network I was able to get the excel file with 5-6 minutes of execution of the Ajax.

But when my client execute this, in a different geography as where I am, the ajax request will expire (timeout) for 30 seconds ONLY! I dont understand why only 30 seconds but when I execute this it will reach up to 6 minutes.

in my php.ini, I already set this up:

```
 max_execution_time = 0
 max_input_time = 0
```

and in my php, I put this up in the start of the script:

```
    set_time_limit(0);
```

in my ajax request, BTW I am using EXTJS 4:

```
  Ext.Ajax.request({
      url: 'validurl',
      params: {},
      method: "POST",
      waitMsg: "Exporting data. Please wait....",
      timeout: 900000,
  ......
  ......
```

What/Where could be the issue?application?network?server? how do I resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: If your request takes 6 minutes, consider another approach, like generating the file offline, then notify the user when the work is done. You cannot require the user to gaze at your page during 6 minutes, waiting for the ajax request to complete.

Comment: Yes, you are right and you have a good point. But still the problem still exist to why the ajax request only takes 30seconds. What if I need to display the data and the user used a filter where a large amount of data is retrieve, what happens then. I just really need to resolve this issue then move to another task. But yes you have a great point, I'll take that to consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the timeout config in the Ext.Ajax singleton:

```
Ext.Ajax.timeout = 360000;
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url : '',
    params : {},
    method: 'POST'
});
```

Comment: isn't it Ext.Ajax.timeout = 36000? yes I already put that in unfortunately still unable to test  because like I said it does not happen when I replicate it and my point of contact is not yet available